# How will you make a webdeveloper resume in 2012?

Tags: resume, websites, europass

It's been a while since the last time I updated my resume.

Now it's time to give it a refresh, but even if I have a strong experience and I worked recently on many big projects my resume "feels" quite old. Maybe is the format (in Europe we have [europass](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/en/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions) that is a standard) that doesn't fit the work of a developer, I don't know.

Or maybe it's only me: it's 2012 and I start thinking that showing a list of projects and a bunch of acronyms in a CV like PHP, HTML, JS, CSS, whatever is quite boring for a recruiter.

Nowadays I see around the web some sorts of "infographics" resumes, but I don't really like them... I want to look at the same time professional and modern...

**How should I create my new resume to show my skills and not appear boring?**

Comment: Hi Napolux and welcome to The Workplace SE!  We currently have a number of posts with the [resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) tag, and many address aspects of your question.  Right now your question looks like a poll and could be closed, so could you edit your question to clarify the specific problem you are having? Are you wondering if you *should or should not* list your knowledge and projects?  Or if you should have supplemental material and how to present that? Those are just some examples.  Thanks.

Comment: If you would like help determining how to make your question less broad, so that it can be reopened, please ask in [meta] or [chat]. Thanks!

Comment: @jcmeloni: I don't think the question is broad now, maybe reopen?

Comment: @Spoike "How do I make my resume cool" is still classic Not Constructive, still has the same problems jcmeloni mentioned

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As someone that reads resumes from time to time, I'd strongly suggest that you be very conservative with the format of your resume.  Don't worry about the format boring people.  The folks that are reading resumes are generally spending 30 seconds, maybe a minute, scanning the resume to figure out if the candidate is worth interviewing.  Every second that is spent trying to understand an infographic or to figure out where a particular bit of information is located on your resume is a second that we're not reading something that makes us want to interview you.

Plus, the people that are doing the hiring software developers tend to be conservative.  The cost of a bad hire is very high and bad hires reflect poorly on the hiring manager.  That means that anything you do that is out of the ordinary makes it riskier for the hiring manager to hire you.  If the hiring manager hires someone that graduated from a top college, presented a traditional resume, dressed well on the interview, interviewed well, etc. and turns out to have been a bad hire, it's relatively easy to conclude that the hiring manager did everything right and that it was just bad luck.  If the hiring manager hires someone that was obviously "non-standard" in some way-- no degree, unconventional resume, etc.-- even if they're otherwise highly qualified, it's relatively easy to conclude if things don't work out that the hiring manager missed a red flag.

Answer (score 2):

Many recruiters and HR departments prescreen all resumes for keywords, so it is critical to keep the skills list in there. Don't worry about boring the computer that does this. YOU need this stuff to make it to the hiring managers desk.

Then you need to impress the hiring manager. Nothing succeeds in this better than having specific accomplishments - so you need to describe your role in the various projects you have done.

Then back to HR and their need to check your work history if you are one of the final candidates, so a list of companies, titles and dates is needed.

Skip the objective section, this just wastes space.